# So I have the file it is looking for but it is not finding the file and turning it into an array

Tags: java, arrays

Im suppose to make a code that takes a txt file and puts it into an array. I need to find the average of the txt file, the standard deviation, and the mode. I have coded out all of it but it is not picking up the file that I do have. I tried doing an exact files location even.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Stats {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fileName = "C:\numbers.txt";
        int nums[] = new int[101], num;
        try {
            Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            while (fileReader.hasNextInt()) {
                num = fileReader.nextInt();
                nums[num] += 1;
            }
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: could not find the input file.");
            return;
        }

        long total = 0;
        int count = 0;
        double average;

        //Find the average of the list of numbers.
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[i] != 0) {
                total += i * nums[i];
                count += nums[i];
            }
        }
        average = total * 1.0 / count;
        System.out.println("Average: "+average);

        double squareSum = 0;
        //b. Determine the difference of each number from the average, and square
        // each difference.
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[i] != 0) {
                //Sum all the differences.
                squareSum += nums[i] * (Math.pow(i - average, 2));
            }
        }
        //Divide this sum by (the number of values - 1).
        squareSum = squareSum / (count - 1);
        // d. Take the square root of the above division result from step
        double standarDeviation = Math.sqrt(squareSum);
        System.out.println("Standard Deviation: " +standarDeviation);

        // Find the mode now
        int maxNum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<nums.length;i++){
            if(nums[i]> nums[maxNum]) maxNum = i;
        }
        System.out.println("Mode: "+ maxNum);

    }
}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

output

Average: 49.91791791791792
Standard Deviation: 29.453867826299614
Mode: 10

Comment: `String fileName = "C:\numbers.txt";` is "C:" followed by a line break, followed by "umbers.txt". You want `String fileName = "C:\\numbers.txt";`, which is just that: "C:" followed by a backslash, followed by "numbers.txt".

Comment: So I did this and still, nothing changed the output is still "Error: could not find the input file." Is there anything else I could do?